# Google Calendar: cannot call getEvents method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get all the events in a calendar using the Script Editor.

```
function getEvents() {

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('aaa@bbb.com');
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("01/01/2018 12:00 AM"), new Date("12/31/2018 11:59 PM"));

  for(i=0; i<events.length;i++){

    var title = events[i].getTitle()
    Logger.log(title)

  }
}
```

I'm returning an error in line 4. It says:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of null. (línea 4, archivo
>   "Calendar")Ignorar

What's wrong and how should it be fixed?

Thanks a lot

Comment: your cal variable is null, I guess the ID is not correct, check it in the calendar parameters

Comment: @Sergeinsas that was the reason. I was entering another user calendar – not my own calendar.

I guess that if i want to get the events in another user Calendar i should first request access and then run the macro.

As I'm testing I haven't done it yet but if that's the cause i would say you answered the question. Thnx!